# Is it legal to use an HTML / CSS generator on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, generator

I created a text fade using the following website:

http://patorjk.com/text-color-fader/

Is it legal to copy and paste the code generated from this generator onto a website? My website does not have any ads and I don't get any revenue from the website.

Also is it legal to copy and paste  one question of a Stackoverflow question javascript code into a website?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Surely the whole point of the site you link to is to provide you with html code that you can reuse elsewhere? Why would there be a legal problem with using the site as per its own instructions?

Comment: This might be a better post for meta.

Answer (score 3):

Code generators are authoring tools. The owners of the site have the right to restrict who uses it but they do not have copyright of material you create with it. Just as Cannon do not own the photos you make on their cameras or BIC owns the poem you write with their pen. Even if the site says code created via their tool is their copyright, it is not so, it is not enforceable, and may even be illegal.

Copyright falls to the author, and I am unaware of any country that this is not true. Generators are authoring tools.

Comment: Exactly, you can't own the code, but you can own the generator. I'm up-voting this.

Comment: Actually, they can restrict usage of the tool and material generated with it (e.g. saying it is only for teaching, experiments, not for production, etc.). If this is not stated, we are in a grey zone as the tool code can fall under copyright law depending on countries, which can even restrict code execution (hence using the tool). But in the very case described, the website clearly suggests that you can use the generated material for whatever purpose you want. As for using the tool itself, it does not say anything, so we would be left with fair use (for U.S.)

Comment: A tool that generates code for you isn't quite the same thing as a Bic pen which can't do anything on its own. But having said that, code generation tools *are* normally intended to produce code that you can actually go ahead and use.

Comment: Nor can a code generator create code on its own. Both the pen and the generator require the input of an author to function, the analogy is very apt here.

Comment: So can I use this generator saftely on my website without getting into any trouble?

Comment: You can not use the generator, you did not create it, and it has copyright unless stated. You can use what you made the generator generate as that is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Different websites can have different licences on the content contributed by users or they present. If you use a tool, it is fine and you own the code. It is like you use an editor to create your own project.

As to Stack Overflow, you can see at the bottom: 
"user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required".

So, user posts/answers on Stack Overflow go under the terms of [the Creative Commons license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons). Mostly this is ok, but it may affect/conflict with your software licence.

Generally, you are expected to write your own code but you can still look at Stack Overflow answer/discussion and make your own code instead of copy-pasting.

Especially when it comes to commercial/company projects or any project of which licence is not compatible with this one,

In short, knowledge/experience is not licensed - you can learn and then your can apply that knowledge to make your own code.

It is mostly the case because only small snippets are posted on stackoverflow and it is useful to get insight into the problem puzzling you.

Still, you should honestly show credit/attribution to the idea originator/author etc. if it involves work of somebody.